# What is an example input that can exploit SQL Injection from the following code snippet?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, owasp, htmlspecialchars

I know this code is vulnerable since the PHP function *htmlspecialchars* does not encode all special characters. However, I cannot seem to exploit it. Any help?

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE schoolinfo SET schoolname = \"".htmlspecialchars($_POST["schoolname"])."\"");
```

PS: Database is a MySQL Version 5.5, the schoolname table also can an address column.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` has nothing to do with sql injection.  Maybe you're confusing it with `mysql_real_esscape_string`?  Regardless, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated, please use PDO instead.

Comment: @Madbreaks I understand that htmlspecialchars has nothing to do with SQLI, however it's been used by a web application I'm testing and I've seen it wrongly recommended in some blogs as a solution to SQLI. (http://pantuts.com/2013/03/02/php-sql-injection-prevention/)

Comment: So you can tell that some blogs' authors have absolutely no clue